# Using namespaced models with polymorphic assocations in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) I am trying to manage my polymorphic `Region` with two classes, one namespaced and one not.

```rb
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Event::Exhibition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, as: :contentable
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, as: :contentable
end
```

Everything works bar the ajax fetch of instances of namespaced models.

When I try and select an `Event::Exhibition`, for example, I see this in my browser's console.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #event::exhibition-js-options rails_admin.js:1502:8
    error http://localhost:3000/assets/rails_admin/rails_admin.js:1502
```

When I select `Post` all of my posts are returned as expected.

Is this a bug or should I be able to work around this with different settings? The only config I have for this is to tell Rails Admin to use the field.

```rb
edit do
  field :contentable
end
```

Digging into the HTML and JavaScript a bit more (thanks @[Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412528/guillermo-siliceo-trueba)) I noticed the generated dropdown looks like this.

```html
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Event::ArtFair">Art fair</option>
<option value="Event::Exhibition">Exhibition</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Post">News article</option>
```

When either option with a value `Event::` is selected, Sizzle complains, throwing a syntax error.

In my code inspector, if I escape the colons, making the values `Event\:\:ArtFair` and `Event\:\:Exhibition` things work as expected.

Comment: Have you checked the generated javascript? it might provide a clue of whats going on. Just inspect the page on chrome and it would also help us if you paste in your question the ofending line.

Comment: Good shout @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba, I have added some more information and been able to work out the cause of the JS error, now I just need to work out how best to mitigate 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, those are not valid js identifiers. I think you can scape the values if you defined the content of the select by adding the _enum instance method.

First you need to get a list of possible contentables for the model.

I'm shooting from the hip here but it should be something like:

```
  def self.contentable_models
    ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.select do |model|
      model.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).any? do |has_many_association|
        has_many_association.options[:as] == :contentable
      end
    end
  end

  def contentable_enum
    self.class.contentable_models.map |model|
      [
        model.name.humanize,
        model.class.name.gsub(':','\:')
      ]
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure about the performance of the `contentable_models` if you have many models it will iterate on all of them to find the contentable you might want to memoize that value.

You might need to define the contentable field as an enum or even the contentable_type field. Not sure